# iOS apps: Auto-renewal subscription + buyout option

Tags: ios, subscription

I am thinking about adopting auto-renewal subscription with a free trial period. Moreover, I would like to let user **purchase the app for good** if they find it useful. Does Apple provide such a buyout option? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unclear question!

Comment: Which part? Please be more specific. I can clarify.

Comment: Try editing your question and try to ask with what you tried and your code for reference with images of the question! Otherwise you'd probably have to delete this question